# cannot find module 'config-chain'

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

This is my first post, so forgive me for formatting issues. I was following this  mean.io tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aMNWYpG5sk. It basically gets you to the point where you can locally access the default web app. I was able to do so successfully.The video then suggests to run>

```
    mean package myTheme
```

I received this error...

```
 C:\Users\****\myApp>mean package myTheme
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

I'm running  npm 2.14.7 and node v4.2.3(video uses 4.2.2) on Win 10. I had previously tried this on node 5.3 and received the same error. I also tried cleaning cache & updating npm, bower, and gulp.

I found  C:\Users****\myApp\node_modules\config-chain. Do I need to change something here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I need to provide more information, just ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess something was wrong with mean-cli.

I reran:

```
npm install -g mean-cli 
npm install (inside project folder)
```

My issue was resolved. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: don't get used to `-g` better to get used to `--save` ;)

so: `npm install --save mean-cli`

Answer (score 0):

I just removed and re-installed and everything worked. Go figure. I also had to use sudo because I'm on a mac.

sudo npm install -g ember-cli@2.5

Comment: You should look into using NVM (Node Version Manager) which removes the need to sudo your calls. It can cause massive problems in the long run if you are using sudo for every call

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you install config-chain it installs in your project directory node_modules but cordova add browser is looking in global modules. This is what I did, went outside the directory and ran npm install -g config-chain That resolved this module and asked for more do the same thing for all modules it complains and you should be good.